# Compare values from 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not sure which php function to use for this..

How can I check if one array has the values available in another array?

Fro example, I have a text input where CSV are submitted --- `$str = "green, yellow, blue"`

I use `str_getcsv()`to create an array of the string. Then I want to compare array 1 to array 2 seen below

```
$array2 = array("green","yellow","orange","purple");
```

I'm comparing array 1 to array 2 to ensure that the submitted values are allowed. So if a value in array 1 does not exist in array 2, I want to return `false`. I tried the following but it doesn't work..

```
        $array1 = str_getcsv($str); //create array of colors
        $array2 = array("green","yellow","orange","purple"); //allowed colors

        if (!in_array($array1, $array2)) if value from array1 not in array2
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else 
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
```

Is this more complicated than I thought?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into PHP's [array_diff( )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: +1. I posted array_intersect (removed my answer), but array_diff is better here. It returns indeed the items that are *not* in the other array. So if array_diff returns any values, you know your input is wrong. The returned values are not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use array_intersect() to get the values that are both set in that arrays and then check if value is set in the result.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

You may also use array_diff() and set if the value is not set in the result.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php